# Applying maven filters on properties in Mule Studio

Tags: maven, runtime-error, mule, mule-studio

I have a mule studio project, for which I have defined maven filter for the properties which should be different for different environments.

However, mule studio is not able to apply properties for default environment (local) as a result of which application fails at start up with the following errors.

```
[02-18 20:24:32] ERROR DefaultMuleApplication [main]: null

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'invoke-cj-ws' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'prop1' in string value "${cj.auth.key}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:174)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:119)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:207)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:58)
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:91)
```

Has anyone used successfully filters in MuleStudio OR has used an alternative means of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you define a profile in your pom.xml (or if you like in settings.xml) and mention the build tag with required filter properties for particular environments should be loaded for you, you can verify this when you run mvn package and peek inside the jar to check if the property file was packaged. So, to help you below would be the profile section

```
 <profiles>
  <profile> 
    <id>dev</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <filters>
           <filter>src/main/resources/build/dev.properties</filter>
           </filters>
           <resources>
            <resource>
             <filtering>true</filtering>
             <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
             <includes>
              <include>**/*.xml</include>
              <include>*.properties</include>
             </includes>
            </resource>
           </resources>
          </build>
  </profile>
 <profiles>
</project>
```

Further you need to have a property file inside src/main/resources which would have dynamic values and based on env parameter passed during maven build it would take up corresponding property file from src/main/resources/build folder.